# In my Django Project, I am Trying to execute the python method in by hitting the html button

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

When I am hitting the edit button of my studentUpdate.html file then I am getting following error:-

> NoReverseMatch at /studentUpdate/
>   Reverse for 'update_student' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['update_student/(\d+)/$']

Someone help me.

```
<!-- studentUpdate.html -->

{% extends 'app.html' %}

{% block body %}
    <div>


        <div class="alert alert-info">All Students</div>





        <button id="show_book" type="button"  class="btn btn-success"> 
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-left">
        </span> Back
        </button>


   <div id="edit_form"></div>

        <div id="book_form" > 
            <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <form id="form" method="POST" action="{% url 'students' %}">

                    {% csrf_token %}

                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label >Student ID:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="sid" required="required" class="form-control"/> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>First name:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group"> 
                        <label>Last name:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Department:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="department" class="form-control" required="required"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Section:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="section" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Year:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="year" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button name="save_book" id="save_book" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'update_student' %}"><span
                                class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>
                            Update

                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>



{% endblock %}


{% block scripts %}
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () 
        {
            $('#table').DataTable();
        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#add_book').click(function () {
                $(this).hide();
                $('#show_book').show();
                $('#book_table').slideUp();
                $('#book_form').slideDown();
                $('#show_book').click(function () {
                    $(this).hide();
                    $('#add_book').show();
                    $('#book_table').slideDown();
                    $('#book_form').slideUp();
                });
            });
        });

        $('.editButton').on('click', function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:8000/edit_book/' + id,
                method: 'GET'
            }).success(function (response) {
                {#                alert(response.title);#}
                $('#form')
                    .find('[name="title"]').val(response.title).end()
                    .find('[name="description"]').val(response.description).end()
                    .find('[name="author"]').val(response.author).end()
                    .find('[name="quantity"]').val(response.quantity).end();
                document.getElementById('save_book').innerText = 'Update';
                $(this).hide();
                $('#show_book').show();
                $('#book_table').slideUp();
                $('#book_form').slideDown();
                $('#add_book').hide();
                $('#show_book').click(function () {
                    $(this).hide();
                    document.getElementById('form').reset();
                    $('#add_book').show();
                    $('#book_table').slideDown();
                    $('#book_form').slideUp();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

**Here is my Url.py file**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views
from django.urls import path, re_path

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^index$', views.index),
    url(r'^books$', views.books, name="books"),
    url(r'^categories$', views.categories, name="categories"),
    url(r'^students$', views.students, name="students"),
    url(r'^returning$', views.returning, name="returning"),
    url(r'^borrow$', views.borrow, name="borrow"),
    url(r'^edit_book/(\d+)/$', views.edit_book, name="edit_book"),
    url(r'^edit_category/(\d+)/$', views.edit_category, name="edit_category"),
    url(r'^delete_book/(\d+)/$', views.delete_book, name="delete_book"),
    url(r'^delete_category/(\d+)/$', views.delete_category, name="delete_category"),
    url(r'^delete_student/(\d+)/$', views.delete_student, name="delete_student"),
    #url(r'^studentUpdate/(\d+)/$', views.studentUpdate, name="studentUpdate"),
    path('studentUpdate/', views.studentUpdate), 
    url(r'^update_student/(\d+)/$', views.update_student, name="update_student"),
]
```

**Here is my views.py file**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.db.models import Sum
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.
from library.models import Book, Category, Student, Borrow
import playsound
from django.template import loader 




def index(request):
    return render(request, "index.html", {})


def categories(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        title = request.POST['title']

        Category(title=title).save()
        return redirect('/categories')
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    return render(request, "category.html", {"categories": categories})


def delete_category(request, id):
    category = Category.objects.filter(id=id)
    category.delete()
    return redirect('/categories')


def edit_category(request, id):
    category = Category.objects.filter(id=id).get()
    return JsonResponse({'title': category.title})


def books(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        title = request.POST['title']
        author = request.POST['author']
        cat = Category.objects.get(id=int(request.POST['category_id']))
        description = request.POST['description']
        available = int(request.POST['quantity'])

        book = Book(title=title, author=author, description=description, available=available)
        book.save()
        if book.categories.add(cat):
            return redirect('/books')
    books = Book.objects.all()
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    return render(request, "books.html", {"books": books, "categories": categories})


def edit_book(request, id):
    book = Book.objects.filter(id=id).get()
    return JsonResponse(
        {'title': book.title, 'author': book.author, 'description': book.description, 'available': book.available})


def delete_book(request, id):
    book = Book.objects.filter(id=id).get()
    book.delete()
    return redirect("/books")




def students(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        sid = request.POST["sid"]
        firstname = request.POST["firstname"]
        lastname = request.POST["lastname"]
        department = request.POST["department"]
        section = request.POST["section"]
        year = request.POST["year"]

        student = Student(student_id=sid, firstname=firstname, lastname=lastname, department=department,
                          section=section, year=year)
        student.save()
        return redirect("/students")
    students = Student.objects.all()
    return render(request, "students.html", {"students": students})



def borrow(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        student_id = request.POST['student_id']
        student = Student.objects.get(id=student_id)
        status = "Borrowed"
        books_id = request.POST.getlist('selector')
        for book_id in books_id:
            book = Book.objects.get(id=book_id)
            b = Borrow(qty=1, status=status)
            b.save()
            b.student.add(student)
            b.book.add(book)
            return redirect("/borrow")
    students = Student.objects.all()
    books = Book.objects.all()
    datas = []
    for book in books:
        left = Borrow.objects.filter(status="Borrowed", book__title=book.title).aggregate(Sum('qty'))
        if left['qty__sum'] is None:
            l = 0
        else:
            l = int(left['qty__sum'])
        datas.append(book.available - l)
    return render(request, "borrow.html", {"datas": zip(books, datas), "students": students})



def delete_student(request, id):

    student = Student.objects.filter(id=id).get()
    student.delete()
    return redirect('/students')





def returning(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        b_id = int(request.POST["borrow_id"])
        borrow = Borrow.objects.get(id=b_id)
        borrow.date = datetime.now()
        borrow.status = "Returned"
        borrow.save()
        return redirect('/returning')
    borrows = Borrow.objects.all()
    return render(request, "return.html", {"borrows": borrows})

def studentUpdate(request):
    template = loader.get_template('studentUpdate.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render()) 


def update_student(request,id):
    return redirect('/students')
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Django, but why is `path('studentUpdate/', views.studentUpdate)` different than everything else around it? That's also where the error is occuring.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to submit a form (which already has a target url, here it is `students`), you do not need to specify any `href` when setting your submit button, you have to check that.

Then, what does your error message say? It says you want to use a url shortname that does not refer to anything in your `urls.py` file. So, you have to check this out precisely. It does not have anything related to the form itself: just loading your page on a `GET` request will generate an error, because Django can not understand what you want to achieve.

It is not clear for us to help, because you have too many confusing definitions of what you try to achieve. Just show one solution at a time, only one `update_student` view, same goes for urls. Comment everything looking like "update_student" except this one: `url(r'^update_student/(\d+)/$', views.update_student, name="update_student")`.

Finally, your error message indicates that you are not passing any argument to your url, but arguments are expected (see the `(\d+)` in your url definition). So, make a few more research to understand how to pass arguments to your `{% url ... %}` stuff, you are close to have something not generating any error on a `GET` call. Good luck! :-)

Comment: can I use href in <button> tag

Comment: You can but it won't do what you are trying to do. So no!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
<button name="save_book" id="save_book" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'update_student' %}">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>
 Update
</button>
```

Because the way you have defined the url for the **update_student** function it must be called with some argument of integer type.

For example:

```
<a href="{% url 'update_student' 5 %}">Click Me</a>
```

*In the above example the integer **5** is passed as an argument.*

Because you are not passing any argument with the **update_student** url so only you are getting the error which you mentioned in the question.

I hope it will help you!!

Comment: I don't know it will work or not. Because now I have done this by using Ajax call in django

Comment: @Abhishek well that's good bro but the error which you were getting is just because of the reason that you didn't passed the argument.But still its really nice to know that you solved your problem by your own.:)

Comment: By the way thanks Brother. I have learned something from you.